# Html2Canvas images getting cropped

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas for taking screenshots of the page. The images on the page are getting cropped. I have tried a lot of settings but nothing seems to fix this.
Pasting my code below

```
// Function to load the html2canvas library
    function loadHtml2Canvas() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        script.onload = () => {
            captureAndDownload();
        };
    }

    // Function to capture the DOM and download the image
    function captureAndDownload() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            logging: true,
            useCORS: true,
            allowTaint: true,
            onclone: function() {
                console.log('args');
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        }).then(canvas => {
        // Convert canvas to data URL
            const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

            // Create a temporary link element
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.download = 'captured_image.png'; // You can change the filename and format if needed

            // Append the link to the body and trigger the click event
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();

            // Remove the link from the DOM
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        });
    }
```

Also, I have noticed not all the images on the page get cropped some do and some don't, and also that too is very random ( sometimes one gets cropped and sometime some other one ).

Attaching images of the expected and actual parts of screenshot( Please ignore overlay on the required image)

Expected Image : [image: Expected Image]

Required Image : [image: Required Image]

Tried different configuration options but nothing helped.

Comment: I tried this code in one of my React applications and it works. Please, provide the rest of the code or provide example code of the representation of the problem, which can be executed without much effort.